# "Searching..." takes forever on readthedocs when the phrase is not present on the page

Tags: python, full-text-search, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

When I search for a phrase which is not present on the readthedocs page, I get the message:

"Searching...", which will take forever. On the contrary, when I search for some known phrase, I get the results within a second.

I have looked into page's console:

> The resource from “https://xxxxxx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/css/yy.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
> Read the Docs search failed. Falling back to Sphinx search.

I have tried:

1. [conf.py] I have line:

   ```py
   html_css_files = [
       "css/yy.css",
   ]
   ```

so I added:

`app.add_css_file(html_css_files)`  in `def setup(app):`

but this caused build error in readthedocs

2. I have added in conf.py:

   ```py
   notfound_urls_prefix = "/projects/xxxxxx/en/latest/"
   ```

but this also didn't help.

Have you encountered something similar? If so, how have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the root-cause was somewhere else.
When I looked into raw output on rtd, I found out that sphinx_rtd_theme was installed with 0.4.3, which is not the latest. The latest is 0.5.2. So I pinned the latest version in my docs/requiremets.txt. This fixed the searching problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. I fixed it by removing this line in the `conf.py` file:

```py
html_theme_path = [sphinx_rtd_theme.get_html_theme_path()]
```

After doing that, rebuilt the doc, and the problem was solved for me.